# Facbook events doesn't works on iOS

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

When I start my app I always receive this message:

```
[connection] nw_resolver_start_query_timer_block_invoke [C35.1] Query fired: did not receive all answers in time for graph.facebook.com:443
```

I am using this plugin: https://pub.dev/packages/facebook_app_events

The events works perfectly fine on Android. I've tried many options (the ones I found on the internet) but none of it worked.

Comment: Have you tried debugging how this lib works step by step? Looks like there must be an issue for iOS so possible solution is the Xcode configuration, I'd dig with .plists first and test whether your configuration and back-end setup works for native solution (`Swift`). Looks like you're not the only one struggling on the iOS side: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64255000/iosfoursquareapi-error-connection-nw-resolver-start-query-timer-block-inv

Comment: I already tried. But I will try again anyway. I decided to open an issue on GitHub. I hope someone helps me with it or that I find a solution!

Comment: Can you share the link @Acorcdev

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on iOS 14+ do check this App tracking permission that is required for events tracking.

https://developer.apple.com/app-store/user-privacy-and-data-use/#permission-to-track

Also, while testing on real device (iOS) check if your device's facebook app "Allow Tracking" is allowed. You can do this by checking facebook's permissions from Settings.

Comment: It didn`t work it all. I' am still facing it on iOS.

Comment: Same here. Anyone who did manage to make it work? We're using SPM Facebook 12.3.1. But we can't receive any events, even though we set the flag inside info.plist 

 <key>FacebookAdvertiserIDCollectionEnabled</key>
 <string>TRUE</string>.

Comment: Hey @Grumme I found a solution. Check it out!

Answer (score -3):

I finally found a solution for it.

In the main.dart I just need to call:

```
FacebookAppEvents().isAdvertiserIDCollectionEnabled(true);
```

And then it worked.
I hope it works for you too!

Comment: I'm doing Swift, so I'm already using the following line of code.
Settings.shared.isAdvertiserTrackingEnabled = isEnabled. We started getting the flag in after 2/3 (Same day Facebook deprecated existing API). But we don't get any data in regarding app installations.

Comment: no such method.